# what exactly does painless do under the hood of painless script's Array contains method

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Suppose that i have a doc mapping field like below

```
{
    "template": {
        "mappings":{
            "template":{
                "properties": {
                    "sth": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The field `sth` is the type of array.

I want to check whether the field `sth` contains a value or not, so i write painless script like
`doc['sth'].values.contains(1)`

It failed, and i read this [article](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painless-collection-contains-not-working/178944), understand why it fail, since the i must pass a
`Long` to the `contains` method, so i change my painless script to
`doc['sth'].values.contains(1L)`

It works, but some further experiment exhaust me more.

The script

`doc['sth'].values[0] == 1` and `doc['sth'].values[0] == 1L`

both can work, ok, i read the [painless document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-operators-boolean.html#equality-equals-operator), understanding that the integer type will be promoted as long type.

But `doc['sth'].values[0] == Integer.valueOf(156)` also can work, however, according to the document

> If a comparison is made between a primitive type value and a reference type value.

Should it raise an error? Or automatically unboxing/boxing happens somewhere?

Nevertheless, i wrote script 
`doc['sth'].values[0] instanceof Long` and `doc['sth'].values[0] instanceof long`, 
both can work and return true.

Is painless array type store the primitive type, or the boxing reference type?

Finally, comes to the topic question, what exactly does painless do under the hood of painless script's Array contains method.

It's just my irresponsible guess

Is `Array::contains` have a signature like `contains(Object o)`, and use `==` to 
compare the parameter with its storage?

But if its the truth, why does `doc['sth'].values[0] == 1`
success but `doc['sth'].values[0] == 1` fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` is actually of type [`ScriptDocValues`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.java) (an abstract subclass of `AbstractList`). For a field typed with `long`, the actual concrete implementation is [`ScriptDocValues.Longs`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.java#L81-L131).

So to answer your question, under the hood, the `.contains()` method will simply delegate to `AbstractCollection.contains()` which calls `.equals()` under the hood. This is why `doc['sth'].values.contains(1)` fails while `doc['sth'].values.contains(1L)` succeeds.

As you can see, the values are internally stored in a `long` array (primitive type). However, the `get()` method returns a `Long` (boxed type) in order to satisfy the `AbstractList` contract and the `getValue()` returns a primitive `long` unboxed from the call to `get()`. This is why both `doc['sth'].values[0] == 1` and `doc['sth'].values[0] == 1L` succeed.

If you call `get()` and there's no doc value, you'll get an `IllegalStateException` stating that you should...

> use doc[].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. So ```.values[index]``` returns primitive type, thus promotion happens when the operator ```==``` is called. But ```.contains()``` use ```.equals()``` to compare the inner storage value and the argument, so the inner storage type ```long``` is wrapped as ```Long```, is that correct?

Comment: Since `contains` uses `equals`, that's the reason why `contains(1)` fails and `contains(1L)` succeeds, because 1 is boxed to an Integer and 1L is boxed to a Long and a Long can only be equals to a Long.